# Unity can't adjust the camera right for phone app. Any thoughts?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I created a new project in which I've set my display to be 1440 x 2960. I made a background in PSD with the exact same size, and when I place it in the scene, it appears to be way bigger than the actual camera, which should obviously be the same size. Why is that? I'm quite a newbie and I find this very counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing up resolution with camera size/field of view.These are Different things things.
And also how big your object is in your scene also depends on : pixels per unit" that uyou set up in your Graphic asset.